# Build Visual Studio 6 project with Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-6

I am trying to build a project created in VS 6 with VS 2010. When I open `.dsw` file, VS converts the project asking me this message:

> "... ProjectName.dsp must be converted to the current Visual C++
>   project format. After it has been converted, you will not be able to
>   edit this project in previous versions of Visual Studio.
>
> Convert and open this project?"

When I say `"Yes"` VS opens the project. Now, since I must add one header file and a library to build this, I added the `.h` file and `.lib` file paths by setting `VC++ Directories`.

Now, I am not sure when and why, but in some time after this, VS 2010 gives me the following error popup window that keeps showing:

> "Microsoft (R) Visual C++ Package Server has stopped working
>
> A problem causes the program to stop working correctly. Please close
>   the program."

Any help with solving this?

Comment: So, what happens after you close Visual Studio and open the same project again?

Comment: This issue (http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/517763/microsoft-r-visual-c-package-server-has-stopped-working) on Microsoft.Connect points to this being a bug that fixed in the VS2010 release. May be you should also post your details there also.

Comment: @Preet Sangha: I read this page too, when I googled for the error, but I already have VS 2010 and problem is still here.

Comment: @Alex Farber: When I open (newly created) .sln file the popup error shows immediately and keeps popping up...

Comment: I think you should post your problem there also to see if this is a known bug from MS.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem here and the reason was incorrect permissions on an included file. The user running Visual Studio 2010 must (obviously) have read access to the file!

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure if this will be helpful for anyone else but in my case I saw this error and discovered that my hard drive was full. I cleared a few gigs of space and everything worked again.